# VIM Flashing Issue

Tags: macos, ssh, vim, macvim

I'm SSH'ing in from my mac OSX (10.6.8) to a school server running centOS5 and when I attempt to use VIM, it won't stop flashing inside the mac terminal. Any idea's on how to fix this? Keep in my mind I do not have the authority to modify any /etc files or /bin files on the server, although I believe I can locally on my user. Also I would love to see anyone's really cool .vimrc config file they want to share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I´ve just had the same issue.
 
I solved it by disabling the setting **"Allow blinking text"** in the terminal text settings
 as shown in this
[screenshot](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=344).

Regarding .vimrc config there are tons of versions to be found on google, especially github is a good place to go.

Comment: was having this problem on Mac 10.6.8 in terminal window while ssh'd into a local vagrant vm.

Answer (score 9):

Try these out:

```
 set visualbell t_vb=    " turn off error beep/flash
 set novisualbell        " turn off visual bell
```

Though the link may go stale in the future, for the time being this is the source:  http://phuzz.org/vimrc.html

I also know that you can set this via terminal options on the MAC, though this is not likely the issue if you are ssh-ing.  Anyway, I hope it helps.  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 5):

to stop beeping & flashing in both the console & the GUI versions of Vim try:

`set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=`

`autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=`

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty frustrated with macvim installed via brew.

First, on installation, it had ***an issue with the python version.***

I did upgrade brew and python. Then I started macvim but it was ***flashing really bad,*** to eliminate, I had to ***disable core text renderin***g under `preferences -> advanced options.`

Finally, it got stable but ***couldn't open files or tabs.***

> objc[80401]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/FinderKit
>   (0x10d099200) and
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
>   (0x115309c00). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

So I decided to get rid off it altogether.

```
brew uninstall --force macvim
```

Installed it manually [from here.](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-151)

Once installed, I used the following command to create an alias. Add the following line to your .bashrc or .zshrc (for iTerm users).

```
alias mvim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim -g
```

Now reload your terminal session and type mvim. Enjoy!!