# Flickering window while using gvim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, macos-mojave

I am seeing a flashing or flickering window when I try to open a file using 
`gvim <filename>` command.

I am not sure if it is Mac OS related problem. I have installed macvim using `brew` ([How can I install MacVim on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/how-can-i-install-macvim-on-os-x)).

Please do not flag this post though there exists a similar post: [VIM Flashing Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935345/vim-flashing-issue) as the problem doesn't get resolved by following the answers (the most voted answer mentions a screenshot whose link is broken).

I'm using the latest macOS Mojave (10.14).

Answer (score 7):

I had success by disabling the "Use Core Text renderer" in the advanced preferences for MacVim. To fully activate the new settings I also had to quit the MacVim app and launch again.

Also, check your settings found in Edit navigation bar.

Comment: Yup, this works for me, thanks. My next question is why MacVim has an option to use Core Text. The documentation for that API says it's for low-level development.

Comment: MacVim developer, bjorn, writes: The reason I was pushed to change the default renderer now was because 
Apple has made changes to NSTextView which completely changes its 
rendering appearance on OS X 10.8 (lines are *a lot* taller than 
before).  The Core Text renderer on the other hand looks uniform 
across platforms.  Another belated reason is that high-res displays 
are becoming quite common (and of course now there are even Retina 
displays).  The NSTextView renderer struggles with these high 
resolutions, whereas the Core Text renderer does not. I found it on the MacVim forum.

Answer (score -1):

I could resolve this issue after opening the X11-term application XQuartz.

Comment: Not very helpful.